# in an angular 13 solution, whats the best and quickest way to reset the html template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

on the html are input fields and selects and arrays of filenames

I tried writing a single method to reset each element on the form, then I added more fields so I needed to add to my reset function. Is there a way that the function could be less explicit?

Comment: [`@ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#usage-notes)

Comment: have you looked at [FormGroup.reset()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset)